# Poetry pyproject.toml not updating after running 'poetry add' inside project

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, python-poetry

I have a django project, with a single virtual env by poetry. At the root of the project is a `pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock` file. Within that folder, if I run `poetry shell` my virtual env activates and I can run my code.

When I run `poetry add slack-sdk`, slack-sdk is installed and I can use it in my activated virtual environment. The environment seems to update as the code does indeed run - I'm using VSCode and have my virtual env selected at the bottom.

However, the `pyproject.toml` file doesn't update, so when I try and run on the server, the dependencies don't show up. How can I have my poetry environment behave the way I expect, which is the pyproject.toml updates each time I add something?

````
poetry env info`
Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.4
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-xNHOe2Gk-py3.9
Valid:          True

System
Platform: linux
OS:       posix
Python:   /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4
```
````

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by deleting all the poetry envs in my `.cache/virtualenvs` folder, and then running `poetry install` from within my project again, then `poetry add slack-sdk`, then `poetry update`.

Whatever had gone wrong, deleting and re-installing all virtual envs fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following with @latest tag for each dependency:
`$ poetry add pytest@latest --dev`

Answer (score -2):

my solution `sudo poetry add slack-sdk`